# Update multiple values with WHERE condition without using a for loop in psycopg

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a pandas dataframe (df) with 2 columns, "item_code" and "item_price". I also have a larger postgresql table (items_table) that contains the same 2 columns. The item codes already exist in the sql table without the prices. I want to insert the prices in the postgresql table for the preexisting item codes using the dataframe values without using a for loop.

Basically, I want to achieve what the code below achieves without using a for loop:

```
execution_statement = f"INSERT INTO items_table (item_price) VALUES (%s) WHERE item_code = %s"

list_of_codes = list(df['item_code'])

for code in list_of_codes:
   item_price = float(df[df['item_code'] == code]['item_price'])
   
   Database.initialise(database=databasedb, user=userdb, password=passworddb, host=hostdb, port=5432)                    
   with CursorFromConnectionPool() as cursor:
      cursor.execute(execution_statement, (item_price, code))
      cursor.close()
```

I want to achieve what the code above achieves in one postgresql query without using a for loop. Is that possible?

Comment: You **do not want** an Insert statement Insert always creates complete rows, a row cannot exist with a column that *does not have a value*. That value may be `Null`, but still it is a value. You need an Update statement.  something like: `Update items_table set item_price= %s  WHERE item_code = %s"` Disclaimer: I do not work with pandas dataframe(s) so syntax may be off.